# Implement a Id to differenciate multiple clients that will run the code

Tags: java

I am implementing a code that should simulate a DataBase. In the process, I will run multiple instances/clients of the same code simultaneously and need a way to differentiate each run, because, each time the instance runs itself, it should add a new line to a PlaceHolder.txt file that, when the user (instance) commits the code, it should move only his transactions to the DataBase.txt file.
This is the Transaction class:

```
public class Transaction{

private final String name;
private final int id;

public Transaction(){
    this.id = getId()+1;
    this.name= "T"+id;
}
public String getName(){
    return this.name;
}
public int getId(){
    return this.id;
}

public String toString(){
    return "Name: "+ name+"\nID: "+id+"\n";
}
```

And the Function that calls it, is this one:

```
private ArrayList<Transaction> transaction;
private static int id;
private static String name;

//Not Working
public synchronized String NewTransaction() {
    Transaction transaction;
    transaction= new Transaction ();
    transaction=transaction;
    System.out.print(transaction.toString() + "\n");
    return transaction.toString();
}
```

QUESTION:
But the coding isn't working. When I run the code, the result will always be id=1. What I am doing wrong in the code?

Comment: So, what is the question?

Comment: It is not working. When I run the code, the result will always be id=1.

Comment: You have several options :  1)  if you just need a unique value, and sequence does not matter, generate a UUID.  If you need a unique, incremented, numeric value, save id to a file, and lock access to the file using some sort of inter-process synchronization mechanism.

Comment: How can I do that? Can you give an example?

Comment: I missread your answer. It worked! Thanks OldProgrammer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implementing a solution in line with some of the suggestions:

```
class Junk {

    private class Transaction {
        private final String name;
        private final int id;

        public Transaction(int id){
            this.id = id;
            this.name= "T"+id;
        }

        public String getName(){
            return this.name;
        }

        public int getId(){
            return this.id;
        }

        public String toString(){
            return "Name: "+ name+"\nID: "+id+"\n";
        }
    }

    private ArrayList<Transaction> transactions;
    private int curr_id = 0;
    private String name;

    public synchronized String NewTransaction() {
        curr_id++;
        Transaction transaction = new Transaction(curr_id);
        return transaction.toString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The default value for an int is 0. So, when you construct a new Transaction object, you do this.id = getId()+1; which will always be 1 (0+1).

You could create a new class called something like IdCreator.java with a method public static synchronized getNewId() and a static int idToHandOut and in there you keep track of the last id given out and when someone asks for a new one, you increment it by 1.

There are many other ways to do it too - you could a timestamp as an id.

Basically though, you can't assign ids the way you have it written because it will always be 1.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix it with some modification:

```
class Transaction{

    private static int ID;  // static var for unique identifier

    private final String name;
    public final int id;

    public Transaction(){
       ID++;
       this.id = ID
       this.name= "T" + ID;
    }

    public int getId(){
        return this.id;
    }
 ...
}
```

Now you will get different id's:

```
    Transaction t1 = new Transaction();
    Transaction t2 = new Transaction();
    System.out.println(t1.id); // id 1 
    System.out.println(t2.id); // id 2
```

Comment: This doesn't take into account simultaneous access by calling processes. Incrementing and using ID is not atomic.

Comment: Bit more explanation as per comment from @Barry . The key point here is the fact that `++` is **not** thread safe. Therefore, concurrent execution of this line in multiple threads will produce duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

You better use atomic types in this kind of scenario, though it could potentially introduce the bottleneck under extremely heavy load, but for medium-to-high it should be ok.

```
package transaction;

import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class Transaction {
    // static field to generate new numbers sequentially in thread-safe way
    private static final AtomicInteger idProvider = new AtomicInteger(0);

    private final int id;
    private final String name;

    public Transaction()
    {
        this.id = Transaction.idProvider.incrementAndGet();
        this.name = "T"+id;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return this.name;
    }

    public int getId(){
        return this.id;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return "Name: "+ name+"\nID: "+id;
    }
}
```

Test-example

```
package transaction;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Single threaded test");
        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            Transaction t1 = new Transaction();
            Transaction t2 = new Transaction();
            System.out.println("t1: "+t1.toString());
            System.out.println("t2: "+t2.toString());
        }

        System.out.println("\nMulti-threaded test");
        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            Thread w = new Thread()
            {
                public void run()
                {
                    try{ // simulate unpredictable execution via random delay in instance creation
                        Thread.currentThread().sleep((int)(Math.random()*10));
                    }
                    catch(InterruptedException ignore){}
                    Transaction t = new Transaction();
                    System.out.println(t);
                }
            };
            w.start();
        }

        try{ //Wait for all threads to finish
            Thread.currentThread().sleep(1000);
        }
        catch(InterruptedException ignore){}
        System.out.println("Done");
    }
}
```

Result:

```
Single threaded test
t1: Name: T1
ID: 1
t2: Name: T2
ID: 2
t1: Name: T3
ID: 3
t2: Name: T4
ID: 4
t1: Name: T5
ID: 5
t2: Name: T6
ID: 6

Multi-threaded test
Name: T7
ID: 7
Name: T8
ID: 8
Name: T9
ID: 9
Done
```

P.s. not sure why you do things like

```
transaction=transaction;
```